# Create formatted table in R markdown from TableOne

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
             bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
             amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tableone = CreateTableOne(data = df)
tableone
```

Now I would like to include it in a Markdown and produce a formatted table using some kind of ktable function but obviously it works only for data frames and my variable "tableone" seems to be a list - is that correct?

Is it possible to format ouput of "tableone" as table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this workaround, maybe it helps:

```
library(tableone)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                 bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                 amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tb <-  CreateTableOne(data = df)
k <- print(tb$ContTable)


print(tb$ContTable) %>%
 kbl() %>%
 kable_paper("hover", full_width = F)
```

This leads to this:

[image]

But the function `print()`, prints in your console also the result, so in a markdown, you're going to have also this:

[image]

So you can trick it, dividing the print part and suppressing the output, then print the kable table, in two different chuncks:

````
---
title: "tableone"
author: "S__"
date: "17/8/2021"
output: html_document
---


```{r a echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE, results = 'hide'}  

library(tableone)
library(kableExtra)   

df <- data.frame(age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                 bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                 amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tb <-  CreateTableOne(data = df)
k <- print(tb$ContTable)   

```  
```{r b, echo=FALSE}

 k %>%
 kbl() %>%
 kable_paper("hover", full_width = F)

```
````

[image]